# semi-transparent form but opaque Controls in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, transparency

How to make semi transparent form in C# windows form application

I have tried the `TransparentKey` which makes it full-transparent. and tried `Opacity` but it effects the whole form (with controls).

I want only form part to be semi-transparent but not Controls.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a [hatch brush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.hatchbrush.aspx) with a certain percentage, for example:

```
    using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        var hb = new HatchBrush(HatchStyle.Percent50, this.TransparencyKey);

        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(hb,this.DisplayRectangle);
    }
```

Comment: Oh my. The result is disgusting. Sorry, but it truly is.

Answer (score 3):

I found the Hatch Brush grotesque,

Instead of:

> ```
> protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e) {
>   var hb = new HatchBrush(HatchStyle.Percent80, this.TransparencyKey);
>   e.Graphics.FillRectangle(hb, this.DisplayRectangle);
> }
> ```

I used:

> ```
> protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e) {
>   var sb = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 100, 100, 100));
>   e.Graphics.FillRectangle(sb, this.DisplayRectangle);
> }
> ```

Comment: Perfect, your answer was the only one that served me

Comment: Is it for WPF cause I am not able to find the event as OnPaintBackground in windows forms

Comment: Yes, this WPF not winforms. why use winforms when you can use wpf?

Answer (score -1):

There is a solution which add semi-transparency to a ***Control*** (not *Form*) :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Apply opacity (0 to 255)
        panel1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(25, panel1.BackColor);
    }
```

**In visual Studio :** (alpha activated only during execution)

[image]

**Executed on Windows 7 :**

[image]

**Executed on an old WIndows 2003 Server :**

[image]

Source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4464161/1529139

Comment: The form is not semi-transparent in your example..., or do I miss something?

Comment: Maybe the background is so much uniform and it is not enough clear but it really works with alpha channel. If you watch closely you will see the shading :)

Comment: I have tested and have the following result: The button1 is opaque, the panel1 is semi transparent, the form1 is opaque. You can not see, what is behind the form, but the question was about a semi-transparent form. So I have the same problem, but your answere seems to be not correct...

Comment: I see what you mean, you're true. In facts I've answered  for a `Control` but the question is about the `Form`... I will update

Comment: Who has upvoted this question, just after I have downvoted it? This answere should be deleted, because it leads people into the wrong direction.

Comment: I tried this, and it thrown an `ArgumentException` with the message that the control does not support transparent background colors.