# How to reduce opacity for form only not for controls in c#?

Tags: c#

I want to reduce opacity for form only, not for controls on forms. I reduced opacity for form, but the panel opacity also reduced.

I don't want to reduce panel opacity. How can I to do this using c#?

Comment: _Give me solution_ is never a good way to ask a question here. Show your work first. Tell people where you stuck and what have you tried to solve it.

Comment: Please post the code you used to reduce the form's opacity.

Comment: Post Your Code. And see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638517/make-a-forms-background-transparent)

Comment: public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Opacity = .8;
        }

Comment: i saw that link but panel is also transparency. How to set transparency for form alone?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the opacity for a form, try to set the form to transparent backgroundcolor and use a seperate element (in WPF that could be e.g. a grid) to fill your form and set the opacity there.

Answer (score 0):

Refering to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201315/semi-transparent-form-but-opaque-controls-in-c-sharp), you can use [HatchBrush Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.hatchbrush.aspx).

```
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        var hb = new HatchBrush(HatchStyle.Percent50, this.TransparencyKey);

        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(hb,this.DisplayRectangle);
    }
```