# making panel control transparent

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, opacity

I have a panel control, that has a background picture on it. I want it to change opacity one I move mouse over it. How can I do that? I tried:

```
  btnExit.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(20,63,63,63);
  btnExit.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(20);
```

but nothing changes.. Any ideas why this is not working? this panel is sitting on another panel, which also has background picture. Thanks!

Comment: If you are going to downrate provide a reason (comment)> I counter the cowardly downrate.

Comment: what did I downrate? o_0

Comment: So, do you want the whole control to be semi-transparent?

Comment: @JohnKoerner that is correct. Or at least make it lighter/darker to fake it. Thanks

Comment: Opacity is a tricky thing in winforms controls and doesn't work with overlapped controls. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4464161/573218) for more info

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, as far as I know, with your method, but I guess that you have to refresh the control.

```
btnExit.Refresh();
```

EDIT:

First set your button [FlatStyle to Flat](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/b480e4ef-2ec8-4579-9ca6-7aa5ed23e9f2).

```
this.btnExit.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
```

Then make two functions called btnExit_MouseHover and btnExit_MouseLeave:

```
void btnExit_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  btnExit.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(20, 63, 63, 63);
  btnExit.Refresh();
}

void btnExit_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  btnExit.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(100, 63, 63, 63);
  btnExit.Refresh();
}
```

To activate these functions add two EventHandlers:

```
btnExit.MouseHover += new EventHandler(btnExit_MouseHover);
btnExit.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(btnExit_MouseLeave);
```

This will do the trick, now you only have to change the backcolor to the one you like ;).

Comment: Thanks! The panel control doesn't have flat appearance, so I tried this with both regular button with an image and panel with an image. regular button just changed background color, and panel flickers for a second like it's about to work, but the resets back. I set opacity to 100 for both mousehover and leave, but the same thing happens. Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: I guess when you deactivate the MouseLeave eventHandler it will sort the problem. Or set a if statement/switch in mouseHover and reset the var in MouseLeave