# Make disabled sliders in Winforms appear more 'subtle'

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, slider, trackbar

When you set Enabled = false to a TrackBar, the result looks to the uninitiated user that the trackbar is still enabled (we superusers can tell, but that's only because we know what to look for). How can I make the trackbar more 'greyed out' to appear less 'enabled' ?

In this example, the second slider is disabled, but it looks almost as enabled as the other two.

[image: 3 Sliders - 2nd one disabled]

As one solution, I've tried to change the BackColor of the trackbar control, but that makes it look ugly against the panel background colour. There are no other colour properties. Nor are there any style properties which could've helped.

I also tried overlaying it with a translucent panel by using `panel1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(128, 220, 220, 220);` in an attempt to 'grey' it out more, but the panel doesn't respond to semi-transparency. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463363/how-can-i-set-the-opacity-or-transparency-of-a-panel-in-winforms) asks how to do that, and no answer appears to allows a semi-transparent panel on top of another control (where the control is semi-visible).

Comment: You could disable the labels and the TextBox as well (unless you want the user to be able to use the TextBox while the TrackBar is disabled, which would be weird).

Comment: Ignore the text boxes. In my other example, there aren't any text boxes, just sliders and labels.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What did that do? How was that different from what you wanted? Please explain what research you've done so far, what you've found, and in precise terms why what you've learned so far doesn't address your specific need. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Comment: Oh you actually want me to put some effort into the question? :) I've edited it - see what you think.

Comment: I've expanded further, but one downside to showing research inside the question is that it's extra stuff to read for people who just want an answer, and to have to wade through. Maybe it would be good for research to be in the comments here or a special section if Stackoverflow decides to add that feature.

Comment: If you have just a label it's still good, disable the label. I've done this a lot for very picky clients and never had problems. You can also handle click event and provide additional information as to why this feature is disabled either via message box or an ErrorProvider.