# How to make Transparent Web-browser control

Tags: c#, .net

I have a system windows forms where i show the web browser control over the media-player control as shown in image below,
    [image]

I want to make **Transparent web browser control**. I have try many things but i am not able to make transparency over web  browser control, i have try :

```
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
            this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);
            this.TransparencyKey = Color.Red;
            this.BackColor = Color.Magenta;
            this.TransparencyKey = Color.Magenta;*/
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
            this.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

My code is :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Windows_Video
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Video vdo;

        public string mode = "play";
        public string PlayingPosition, Duration;

        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
          //  VolumeTrackBar.Value = 4;

        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                this.textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            }
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = textBox1.Text;
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();

        }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         /*   OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                this.textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            }*/
        }    

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        //    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = textBox1.Text;
         //   axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            //this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
            this.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        } 
    }    
}
```

Comment: I think you'll find this a lot easier to do in WPF, where every `UIElement` has an `Opacity` property...

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie i also try the opacity property but its not considering

Comment: In WinForms, `Opacity` [only works for `Form`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4464161/622391). That's why I suggested WPF.

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie : u r ryt, but i want to make transparent only web control not a full form

Comment: Then use WPF. WPF is **not** WinForms!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to make another form with a web browser control set the `opacity 50%`  in the `form properties` and then call on button or by some other method it will be work:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Form2 min = new Form2();
            min.Show();
        }
```

By this technique u can set the `opacity` over web browser control/full form