# Not inherrit topmost form opacity

Tags: c#, winforms, transparency, opacity

If I set the opacity of the topmost form all the sub-controls are just as transparent as the form. The same goes for when using the transparencyKey, all the sub-controls have the same transparent color.

What I wish to accomplish it to have controls on the form and **selectively** choose which should inherit this property. Is it possible to do this even if it would require adding subforms to the form?

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated, since I couldn't find any solution that worked for me.

Comment: I have found questions and answers for the reverse of this, making subcontrols transparent, but not the form [How can I set the opacity or transparency of a Panel in WinForms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463363/how-can-i-set-the-opacity-or-transparency-of-a-panel-in-winforms), what I want to do is basically the opposite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is generally not possible, because it is not specific to c#, but the way Microsoft Windows works.

There are 2 ways to get proper transparency on Windows: WS_EX_LAYERED and WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP . Both are inaccessible using Winforms and for good reason: You will have to do any and all painting yourself, including the subcontrols.

WPF does however support this natively.