# A Windows form with opacity, that doesn effect the controls on it, is it possible?

Tags: c#, forms, opacity

I have a form with some opacity. On that form i have a control(Textbox,button)[image] Because the form has opacity, also the controls have opacity. Is there a way to have the form with opacity but the controls on it with no opacity ? p.s. i just want to have 1 form. I know it can be done with more forms but i need only 1. The transparent key property is also useless because i am using that for the hole in the form. some other suggestions??

Comment: so you want the form to be opacity let's say 70 nut the controls to remain at a 100? can you please explain a bit more what is the end result you seek.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30359945/not-inherrit-topmost-form-opacity

Comment: Not possible afaik.

Comment: Yes that is what i want. form to be opacity=70% and controls opacity=100%.. i want to have a tutorial screen. the hole is for the button that the user will click on and the text is for further instructions. so the textbox must have opacity = 100% and the cancel button