# Making A FlowLayoutPanel have a transparent background

Tags: vb.net, flowlayoutpanel

I have a button that dynamically adds up to 24 labels to the form. The problem is their location.

I figured out that instead of manually setting a specific location for each, I can have them automatically arranged like a FlowLayoutPanel does. But the FLP will be on top and hide controls under it. And sending it to back is worse. So i want to bring it to front but keep it transparent, so that it doesn't hide the other controls under it.

Any suggestions will be great

Thanks.

Comment: A `FlowLayoutPanel` is not magic. When you use one, you don't have to specify the `Location` of each child control because it contains the code to calculate them itself. If you're using a `Panel` then there is no such code contained within it so you have to calculate them yourself. There's no way around that. You could inherit `Panel` and encapsulate that code, but you still have to write the code, one way or another.

Comment: @ jmcilhinney - Ok I will edit my post and make things more clear. (Way more clear...)

Comment: If necessary I will post a screenshot of my design

Comment: So, are you saying that you want the `Labels` to appear in front of the image? Have you considered using a `FlowLayoutPanel` and setting its `BackgroundImage`? I've never tried it myself with that control but I would think that it should work.

Comment: No that doesn't, because each picturebox can be panned inside its pannel. I can't make it a simple background image. Also, the the `pic`'s can be zoomed in or out. It looks like I have to either make them all at one place or code their locations one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can have them automatically arranged like a FlowLayoutPanel does.
>   But I can't use one because it will be on top and hide the images in
>   my pic's.

Well, you can use a `FlowLayoutPanel` with a transparent background so it doesn't hide the other controls you have. How to do that? Well, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15523544/4934172) shows you how to make a transparent `Panel`. You should be able to easily adjust it to work with a `FlowLayoutPanel` using something like this:

```vb
Public Class TransparentFLP
    Inherits FlowLayoutPanel

    Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams
        Get
            Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
            cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle Or &H20 ''#WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
            Return cp
        End Get
    End Property
    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaintBackground(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
        ''#MyBase.OnPaintBackground(e) --> Don't uncomment this orelse
                                          'it will cause the BackColor to be redrawn.
    End Sub

End Class
```

- Add a new `Class` to your project.
- Paste the above code into it.
- Rebuild your project.
- Drop the new control from the top of the toolbox onto your form (instead of using the original `FlowLayoutPanel`).
- You're good to go.

P.S. I'm not sure about the use of your 4 panels, but you might consider using a `TableLayoutPanel` instead.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: So you're saying I have make my project again? by copy+paste? Why can't I just add your code to mine?

Comment: Probably put it under my public class. How about that?

Comment: @TGamer, I didn't say make a new project. I said "Add a new Class to your project". Project menu --> Add Class.

Comment: I get it. But what about my `FlowLayoutPanel`'s name property?

Comment: @TGamer, you'll need to delete the existing `FlowLayoutPanel`, use the new `TransparentFLP` instead (which you can name it whatever you want). Hope that's clear :)