# C# How to draw transparent overlays over other controls on Windows form

Tags: c#, forms, overlay

It is a C# and Windows Form project.

Using the immediate example from Visual Studio's own user interface:

1. When a panel is resizing, there is a transparent strip showing the prospective panel size showing over all other controls.
2. When a dockable panel is moved, a transparent docking guide will show up over the prospective docking space.

I am trying to implement the drawing like this, but without success:

**Failed method one:** override OnPaint() of the form, the problem is OnPaint happens before any controls are drawn, so the graphics are always behind any all controls. (I wish there is an AfterPaint())

**Failed method two:** Create graphics from Desktop DC. I can finally draw something over other Controls, but the graphics aren't transparent.

Really appreciated if you have any comments!

Comment: You could use a transparent form: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463363/how-can-i-set-the-opacity-or-transparency-of-a-panel-in-winforms

Comment: So far, that is the best solution.