# Enable dateTimePicker Contorl on doubleClick Event

Tags: c#, .net, datetimepicker

I am using a dateTimePicker control which enable property currently set as false. I want to enable the control on doubleClick but doubleClick event is not available with dateTimePicker.

Comment: Hi Ajeet, can you add some example code?

Comment: A disabled control will not respond to any events.

Answer (score 1):

You could put a [transparent Panel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15523544/7252182) on top of the `DateTimePicker`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        TransparentPanel panel = new TransparentPanel()
        {
            Location = dateTimePicker1.Location,
            Size = dateTimePicker1.Size,
        };
        this.Controls.Add(panel);
        panel.DoubleClick += Panel_DoubleClick;
        panel.BringToFront();
    }

    private void Panel_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dateTimePicker1.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @AjeetKumarSingh: Please remember to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to do this, but you can place the dateTimePicker control inside a System.Windows.Forms.Panel control. In the panels doubleClick event enable the dateTimePicker. See below.

```
private void panel1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.dateTimePicker1.Enabled = true;
}
```